# CMake: GCC preprocessor IMACROS file change does not trigger rebuild

Tags: gcc, compilation, cmake, preprocessor, compiler-flags

I'm using the `-imacros` option for GCC in order to set all preprocessor defines (Options) for a project.

Before `imacros` I have been using a raw file with the preprocessor defines names and with a regular expression in CMAKE I was creating the list of `-D` to put in the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`.

This works fine but ugly to see in the text editor. So to enhance that, I have changed to `-imacros`.

`CMAKE_C_FLAGS` will contain `-imacros` "path to configuration header"

This works fine, but if I change some configuration item in the configuration header the CMAKE do not recompile the file (don't see changes). In the old version - as you can expect - if some `-D` was changed all the files will be recompiled.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### An simple Approach

You can use [`OBJECT_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html) source file property. But that needs to be set for all source files with something like:

```perl
 set_source_files_properties(
     ${sources} 
     PROPERTIES 
         OBJECT_DEPENDS "path to configuration header"
 )
```

#### Alternatives for all Source Files in Project

Officially CMake recommends to put all your definitions in a header file that is included by all your source files. The header could e.g. be generated from a template using [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html).

But to follow your line of thought with using `-imacros` compiler flag, here are two alternative approaches for triggering a rebuild of all source files if "path to configuration header" file changes:

1. You can extend the scope of `OBJECT_DEPENDS` to all targets and their source files in the current directory with [`define_property(... INHERITED ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/define_property.html):

   > If the `INHERITED` option then the `get_property()` command will chain up to the next higher scope when the requested property is not set in the scope given to the command. `DIRECTORY` scope chains to `GLOBAL`. `TARGET`, `SOURCE`, and `TEST` chain to `DIRECTORY`.

   So in your case this translates to:

   ```perl
   define_property(
       SOURCE
       PROPERTY OBJECT_DEPENDS 
       INHERITED 
       BRIEF_DOCS "brief-doc"
       FULL_DOCS  "full-doc"
   )

   set_directory_properties(
       PROPERTIES 
           OBJECT_DEPENDS "path to configuration header"
   )
   ```
2. If I understand correctly, you anyway have to re-run CMake if your "configuration header" should/would change. Then you can simply add one definition outside your "configuration header" that keeps track of the header with something like:

   ```perl
   file(TIMESTAMP "path to configuration header" _timestamp)
   add_definitions(-DIMACROS_TIMESTAMP=${_timestamp})
   ```

   Now every time your header gets a new timestamp, the definitions for all targets are changing and your build system will rebuild all source files.

Comment: Is a huge project, no way. But probably there is a similar solution to make depend the project to that file?

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you for your time and for the recommended version for CMake too :D